# Schedule Number on 1911 census

Tags: census-records

How do I find the house number I have a schedule number from the 1911 census but I would like to know the house number.

Comment: Hello, Susan and welcome to Genealogy & Family History StackExchange. Do you have access to images of the census schedule -- if so, on which site? Knowing this will help us answer. (Even better, do you have the schedule reference?) And can you tell us -- is this for England and Wales or Scotland or Ireland or some other country?

Comment: Please tell us what country you're asking about at the very least so we can give you a better answer.  It would also be useful to know if you only have a citation or if you can see the image yourself.  You can use the edit link underneath your question to add more information.

Comment: Hi I have access to Ancesty so I can look up the census for Acre End Street Eynsham Oxford Oxfordshire. I have been looking for Harper’s and Wickson. My father was born in Acre End Street and I am going to visit Eynsham in April so I would like to find the house where my father was born. His Mother Rose maiden name is Harper married name Hutchison ( my maiden name) . The problem is on any of the census I only have the schedule number.

Answer (score 3):

Well you will have to lookup the census return and see what address is written in the bottom right hand corner.

Note that you will need more than just the schedule number as those are only unique within a piece so you will need the piece number as well - those two together should be enough to do a search on a site like Ancestry or Find My Past that has the census returns available.

If the address in the bottom right is hard to read, or imprecise, then try moving to the next image which should be the front of the census return booklet where you will find the address again, but this time as written by the enumerator when delivering the census returns rather than by the householder when completing it.

Comment: You're assuming that Susan has access to an image of the schedule rather than just a schedule reference.

Comment: Well no, I'm telling her the answer to the question - if she doesn't have access to the images then I don't believe there is any other way to find an address from a schedule number. If you know of one then feel free to add an answer explaining how...

Comment: Then perhaps you could explain how to find the census images, to improve your answer -- however, this depends on the country. Findmypast and Ancestry have Ireland but require a subscription. The Ireland records are available via http://www.census.nationalarchives.ie/search/ (free). Scotland is afaik only available at https://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/research/guides/census-records/1911-census (not free).  And of course, Canada Australia and New Zealand took a census in 1911... So we don't yet know if you've answered the question because we don't know what the question is.